# Elixir-like pipes in Ruby to process collections

Tags: arrays, ruby, functional-programming, pipe, elixir

In Elixir there is a great pipeline operator working like this:

```
"hello, world!"
  |> String.split(" ")
  |> Enum.map(&String.capitalize/1)
  |> Enum.join
```

In Ruby we can use similar syntax:

```rb
"hello, world!"
  .split(" ")
  .map(&:capitalize)
  .join
```

It works only when have all these methods defined for a object itself. If need to call some local method we should use something like:

```rb
.map { |el| URI.parse(el) }
```

But what if we want to make some collection processing (not a single element), for example GZIP Compression:

```rb
chars = text
  .downcase
  .chars

compressed = GZipped.new(chars).bytes
```

But chain is broken!

I've found some links, but looks not awesome:

- [pipe_envy](https://github.com/hopsoft/pipe_envy) - UGLY! no collections
- [chainable_methods](https://github.com/akitaonrails/chainable_methods) - no collections
- [How to use chainable_methods](https://www.akitaonrails.com/2016/02/18/elixir-pipe-operator-for-ruby-chainable-methods)
- [piperator](https://github.com/lautis/piperator) - **much better**! But looks heavy

In my opinion it would be great to have something like:

```rb
text
  .split
  .pipe(URI.method(:parse))
  .map(&:to_s)
  .join
  .pipe(GZIPped)
  .pipe(Base64.method(:encode))
```

**What is the best way to build such pipes in Ruby?**

### Update 1

Here is an example

```rb
class Dedup
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end

  def each
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      prev = nil

      @obj.each do |el|
        if el != prev
          y << el
          prev = el
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


expect(
  "1 1 1 2 2 3"
    .split
    .then { |obj| Dedup.new(obj).each }
    .to_a
).to eq [1, 2, 3]
```

This chaining looks ugly and unreadable.

Comparing to:

```rb
expect(
  "1 1 1 2 2 3"
    .split
    .pipe(Dedup)
    .to_a
).to eq [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: From my experience, trying to make one language mimic another rarely works well. I would rather aim for idiomatic code, going with the language tools that Ruby provides.

Comment: @Stefan could you give provide some `idiomatic` of Ruby-style code doing the same?

Comment: Piping for the sake of piping is discouraged in [tag:elixir] as well. Declare a local variable `chars` and call `GZipped.new(chars)` on it. There is nothing good in long pipes unless you are after fooling your teammates.

Comment: @SergeiO.Udalov the example code seems quite contrived. Do you have an actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes. Real case is to port elixir code to ruby. Yes, we can rewrite it in ruby-way, but it is better to keep it as close as possible.

Comment: Can you share the actual Elixir code? (or something that comes close)

Answer (score 3):

There's already a method like this, at least starting from Ruby 2.5 - `yield_self`, aliased as `then` in Ruby 2.6. You can use `&` operator with any object responding to `to_proc` to pass it instead of a block.

```
text
  .split
  .map(&URI.method(:parse)) # URI#parse expects a string, not an array
  .map(&:to_s)
  .join
  .then(&GZIPped) # not sure what GZIPped is - I'll assume it has .to_proc method
  .then(&Base64.method(:encode))
```

(I should probably mention that the code above will not actually work and honestly I have no clue what it would suppose to do - why would split a string, convert them to into urls and then back again to strings? The only thing this would to is to raise id one of the substrngs were not a valid string? But then you try to read resulting string as a gzipped file... I'm assuming I misunderstood something in your code)

More advanced stuff - one thing that I quite like in elixir was an option to chain methods together with remaining arguments. This also can be simulated in ruby, but requires a bit of work and good think whether it's worth it:

```
module MyMath
  module_function
  
  UNDEFINED = Object.new

  def add(a, b = UNDEFINED)
    if b == UNDEFINED
      return ->(num) { add(a, num) }
    end
    a + b
  end
end

MyMath.add(2,5) #=> 7
[1,2,5,9].map(&MyMath.add(5)] #=> [6,7,10,14]
```

Comment: There's always `.then { |obj| ... }` which allows arbitrary transformations.

Comment: @Stefan @BroiSatse Could you look at 'Update 1' I've provided? Can't understand how to make it readable with `.then`

Comment: @SergeiO.Udalov - To be honest, this would be quite a unreadable thing in ruby - you're trying to mix functional and object opriented programming. Dedup is not a fuction. Buttttt, you can define `self.to_proc` method which returns `->(obj) { self.new(obj).each }` and you could use `then(&Dedup)`. However, this is just very weird

Comment: Real case is to port elixir code to ruby. Yes, we can rewrite it in ruby-way, but it is better to keep it as close as possible. `self.to_proc` worked for me! Thanks a lot, buddy!

Comment: Ruby is multi-paradigm language, why not?

Comment: @SergeiO.Udalov - Yes it is. The problem I have with this is that you have a class that basically acts as a single function, but has no function-like interface, if you rename your `each` method to call, and add a class-level method `call` then your class would be seen as more functional in ruby - there's even a special syntax sugar to make it more prominent - `object,()` executes `call` method.

Comment: Minor comment `MyMath#add` is an instance method and thus not reachable as `MyMath.add()` you would need to change the method definition to `self.add` or add `module_function :add`.

Comment: @engineersmnky - Oh boy, i have a very clear memory of putting `module_functiom` there! Where did it go? 00

Comment: I’d avoid `module_function` application till the end of the scope, it’s extremely error-prone. The proper way would be to explicitly declare `add` in the module scope with `def self.add` _or_ if you insist on having it in both scopes, use `module_function :add` after its declaration.

Comment: To further @AlekseiMatiushkin (which was a lot easier to type when it was mudasobwa) if you want the entire `Module` to be accessible as "class methods" then switch `module_function` to `extend self`